# Android GCM time_to_live issue

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, push-notification

I have a problem related to `time_to_live`. I get messages when the device is on, but when it is offline I don't get the message or at least it is not sent in the first 15 minutes. I'm sending the message with delay while idle true and `time_to_live` 2419200. Any ideas what is happening, maybe I misread the documentation.

Answer (score 18):

From the documentation :

> **delay_while_idle** : If included, indicates that the message should not
>   be sent immediately if the device is idle. The server will wait for
>   the device to become active, and then only the last message for each
>   collapse_key value will be sent. Optional. The default value is false,
>   and must be a JSON boolean.
>
> **time_to_live** : How long (in seconds) the message should be kept on GCM
>   storage if the device is offline. Optional (default time-to-live is 4
>   weeks, and must be set as a JSON number). If you use this parameter,
>   you must also specify a collapse_key.

You don't need to set the time_to_live value to 2419200. It is the default value.However, if you set it you should also set the collapse_key.

> **collapse_key** : An arbitrary string (such as "Updates Available") that is used to collapse a group of like messages when the device is
>   offline, so that only the last message gets sent to the client. This
>   is intended to avoid sending too many messages to the phone when it
>   comes back online. Note that since there is no guarantee of the order
>   in which messages get sent, the "last" message may not actually be the
>   last message sent by the application server. See Advanced Topics for
>   more discussion of this topic. Optional, unless you are using the
>   time_to_live parameter—in that case, you must also specify a
>   collapse_key.

For more details check [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html) again.

Comment: Now you can have just 4 collapse key so use them wisely.

Comment: Apparently you no longer need to set the collapse_key when setting time_to_live: https://plus.google.com/u/0/+FrancescoNerieri/posts/AEpCusdNZY9