# Get list of devices for which GCM notifications delivery was failed

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I have implemented a server which will send some alerts to android devices. For most of devices, Notifications are getting received. However there are few devices to which notifications could not be delivered?

**I would like to know if there is way to get list of such a devices for which notifications delivery was failed?**

Does GCM provides this data(List of devices for which notifications delivery was failed)?

Answer (score 0):

**However there are few devices to which notifications could not be delivered.**

If your devices don't receive notifications, try the following [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20513927/android-gcm-sent-successfully-but-not-received-on-some-devices/20677002#20677002):

- Make sure you've set your SENDER ID you've received from Google correctly.
- Make sure your device was registered with Google's GCM service correctly.
- Make sure you are sending the push to the correct reg id you've received from Google, and that you didn't receive an error from Google GCM service.
- If you set the `delay_while_idle = 1`, the message won't reach the device if it's idle (off, offline, locked screen, etc...). Change it to `delay_while_idle = 0` if you want your [wakelock permission](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-plain-text) to make any difference.
- Some times it takes time for the push to arrive, but if there is too much time, then there is a problem. Check what's the [`time_to_live`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12354690/android-gcm-time-to-live-issue) of the push you've sent.

---

**I would like to know if there is way to get list of such a devices for which notifications delivery was failed?**

Based also from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13967883/android-gcm-delivery-monitoring), Google only provide some statistics that are available on the android developer console. This only shows the number of messages and registrations.

> You would have to implement your own data collection, which could be done fairly easily. You could record the time & id of each message sent and have your android client report back to your server with the time of message receipt. You could then store the data on your server and query as needed.

You can check this [View & diagnose Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) statistics](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2663268?hl=en) link to know your GCM message status.

Comment: I wanted to know if there is some other recommended way to get this done.
I agree with the approach you suggested, it will give me more insight, something that I was looking for.
Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Note that Google Play services is required for GCM to work as expected. If the devices that are not receiving messages do have Google Play services then please raise the issue here: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/